# The idea of In versus On in Latin

Tags: preposition

The Latin word "in" is conventionally given in vocabularies as meaning "in or on" but it seems mean more like "associated with" because it mean attached to or bunch of other things. Its a lot more vague than the English words in or on.

My question is how the Latins expressed the English ideas of in or on. For example, "the rabbit is in the hat" means something different than "the rabbit is on the hat". How would these ideas be expressed in Latin? Obviously you can't say "in petase" because that could mean either in or on.

Comment: You can say something is in the hat like that, although it should be _petaso_ since _in_ takes an ablative when you're saying something is in or on something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic meaning of Latin "in" is "in". The meaning "on" concerns some place. Latin understands a "place" morelike a delimited space, so "in", while in English, it's understood more as a ground lying under something, so "on". In [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in#Latin), the example from Virgil explains it quite well (emphasis mine):

> omne adeo genvs **in terris** hominvmqve ferarvmqve et genvs æqvorevm
> pecvdes pictæqve volvcres in fvrias ignemqve rvvnt
>
> So far does every species **on earth** of man and beast, whether the
> aquatic species, livestock, or painted-winged, collapse into the
> frenzies and the fire.

In (almost? there might be other exceptions) all other cases where "on" is used in English, I would use "super" in Latin.

Answer (score 4):

**in petasō** can't mean "on", only "inside". The "on" in the dictionaries is an artifact of the English usage where the distinction between various prepositions is often vague or associated with particular semantic fields, or even individual words.

That's what a Latin speaker would say, any way, because in Latin there's absolutely no overlap between the word for "inside" **in** and "on top of" **super**, although there is an overlap between the latter and "above" **suprā**. You're always **in viā, forō, aedibus, lūdīs, scholā, īnsulā, terrā**, while in English you're "on the island, mainland, Earth" but "in the building, some country, in school", and either "on the street, forum" or "in the street, forum"... but "at the lesson". Just google for "English on vs in" to find scores upon scores of confused learners.

'Dī bonī!' - exclaims a confused Latin speaker - 'how can **in terrā** be both "in some country" and "on mainland/Earth" (not to mention "in/on the soil"), and **in scholā** both "in school", "in the school" and "at the lesson"? And how in Earth is **in spectāculō, lūdīs** both "at the concert, games" and "in the concert, games"?? And what's that business with "street" and "forum"??' What can one say but shrug? :-]

You could of course try explaining to them that the choice of preposition depends on how the space in question is conceived of by the speakers, and whether it's actually a space or a time referred to metonymically with a word for a space, but that would be like explaining to an English speaker that the choice of perfective vs. imperfective verbs in Russian depends on whether one conceives of the action as a point or a stretch on the timescale. 'But what if I just want to say **in scholā**???'

Comment: +1 but "in the country" is more commonly *ruri*.

Comment: @CMonsour See, another translation artifact! That's not the sense of "in the country" that **in terrā** has; the latter means "in the geographic (political) entity", while **rūrī** means "in the countryside, not in town". One is **in terrā** whether they're **rūrī** or **in urbe** (typically replaced by the locative of whatever city, eg. **Rōmae, Parīsiōs** [yes it's weird like that]). Like those prepositions, they aren't interchangeable.

Comment: English has its own idiomatic requirements.  To translate *in terra* into English, English requires a demonstrative rather than "the" (unless you supply the country's name).  Without a name, the English "in the country" invariably means *ruri*.

Comment: @CMonsour Do you mean that "I'm not in the country right now" cannot mean "I'm abroad"?

Comment: Sure it can.  Negated phrases have their own rules, as always. .

Comment: @CMonsour I don't believe there's an 'always' involved here, only 'in some specific expressions'. What if we try removing the negative: "He's just arrived in the country"? Or "He's been in the country for a week"? Or "I'm not sure whether she's even in the country"?

Comment: "In this country" would be much clearer.  If you utter what you wrote (1st sentence...the others appeared later) in a non-urbanized area and mean *in terra* you are likely to be misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention, I'll definitely need to investigate this. In the meantime I'll clarify my reply.